# Why do I only get 4 turns of Golden Age for Reformation when it says 6?

Tags: civilization-5

Whenever I get Reformation it says it will cause a 6 turn golden age, but invariably it only adds 4 turns. Could this be because I have built Chichen Itza (which increases the length of GAs by 50%) and it is bugged and doesn't always or could there be another reason?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've just tested it and the Golden Age you get from Reformation is unaffected by Chichen Itza or the Great Person shortening.

It is affected by the Persian Unique Ability, which increases the length by 50% to 9 turns.

It is not affected by the game speed, reformation alsways gives you a 10 turns Golden age.

> The length of the Golden age from Reformation no longer scales with game speed since the patch on  15 December 2010

Comment: Yeah, it was a quick game! That explains it.